# pyspark dataframe to tfrecords not working

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

pyspark 3.2.0

I've downloaded spark-tensorflow-connector.jar file from http://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html.

After creating spark session with jar file added
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

```
spark = SparkSession.builder\
            .appName('stc-test')\
            .config('spark.jars', 'spark-tensorflow-connector-1.0.0-s_2.11.jar')\
            .getOrCreate()
```

then when I try to write it into tfrecords following example from tensorflow-spark-connector documentation

```
train_pdf.write.format('tfrecords').option('writeLocality', 'local').save("/tfrecords")
```

I get following error: `Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o152.save. : java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:  Failed to find data source: tfrecords. Please find packages at http://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: tfrecords.DefaultSource`

Can someone help me why? I am new to configuring pyspark so I am not even sure if library is even added to sparksession.

Comment: Just to give you something to try: is the jar file in the correct folder? what is the Scala version you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is because you are trying to run this old package built for scala 2.11 with pyspark 3.2.0

You could switch to this repository and try to use libraries built for spark 3.2.0 -

https://github.com/linkedin/spark-tfrecord

https://central.sonatype.com/search?q=spark-tfrecord&smo=true

Comment: still the same error...